# Critique: iPhone Repair Poster

Tags: critique, information-graphics, posters

I would love feedback on a poster I am making for "Techbox" local tech repair business. There are 3 poster boxes on the outside walls of the business with heavy foot traffic so I'm periodically making posters to swap with whats in the boxes. The focus of this poster is on iPhone repair. The size will be 29"x46"

I have updated this poster since my last question I posted.

Does the poster have a clear message?
Is the poster able to carry the story successfully? or is it too complex and should be simplified?
Does this design have a good balance?

Here is the newest Poster Iteration
[image: Most Recent Design]

Thanks,

-Ivan

Comment: 1 quick comment, it seems weird that #3 is pointing to his finger and not the phone directly unlike the first 2 numbers pointing directly to the phone.

Comment: You may want to review our [critique guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682) and [edit](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/53319/edit) this question. As it currently stands, it's not a question users could provide *objective* answers to and, for that reason, may be placed on hold.

Comment: Sorry about that @Scott, Didn't realize. I will update my question.

Comment: Voted to close pending the update for a specific question.

Comment: @Ryan I have updated the post to include specific questions. Could this be reopened?

Comment: I retracted mine and upvoted. The questions you asked are exactly what I wanted to comment on, so works for me.

Comment: My primary comment (not worthy of an answer) would be that it's just odd to see #3 first. The poster *reads* pretty bad due to this.

Comment: It's a very nice illustration. I don't feel that annotating the 3 steps is necessary at all, though.

Comment: @Scott I have additional questions to ask about this poster but its more about the client designer interactions. Should I start a new question for this?

Comment: If the questions are not related to critiquing or changing this image, then they are most likely new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you first read this poster? how does it flow?

The first thing I found was that its awkward and had to search for #1 then #2 and so on. IF you're going to have a numbered list the design needs to be reconsidered so that they go in a sequential order from top to bottom. Not 1 on top right, 2 on bottom middle, and 3 back at the top.

> Is the use of text redundant and unnecessary?

It is somewhat clear but not so clear I'd say the text is redundant.

> What could be Added/Removed to give a more focused message?

Simplify the message. One statement somewhere in the middle area by what looks kind of like a cutting board. Maybe, "iPhone Repair" "Phone Repair" "Phone Restoration" "Screen Replacement" --- I don't know. But one bold tagline would be better for this design IMO than 3 unordered numbers.

**Update**

On your updated poster I think its a big improvement. I might remove a few scraps and enlarge the tagline though. Looks good though.

Comment: I agree with this.  My eyes instantly went to #3.  Searching for #1 and #2 were very counterintuitive and more work than they should have been, especially for something that's meant to quickly grab the eye of someone walking by.  I also agree that you don't need that much copy.  The artwork pretty much speaks for itself and illustrates the process of an iPhone getting repaired.  One bold headline should be sufficient.

Comment: Hey Ryan, Thanks so much, I simplified the message and posted my updated design in the original question, with additional questions.

Comment: @IvanWitteborg updated my answer

Comment: @Ryan What do you mean by "scraps" ? Thanks for the critiques it really helped a lot!

Comment: @IvanWitteborg the pieces in the middle on the cutboard looking thing.

Comment: I received another critique about this poster from GDF and wanted another opinion.  "that this poster would not be successful in grabbing attention and drawing people in, if it is in a place with mild foot traffic because it is too complex. "

@Ryan and everyone else, What are your thoughts on this comment?

Comment: @FocusedMuffin this is beginning to be a bit off-topic and more marketing. Why don't you come into our chatroom, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot and I'm happy to give my opinion on that in there. (Though it won't be immediately as I'm about to head out.) Essentially though, no this does nothing to pull anyone in IMO. There's no pitch. If you want to pull people in you have to offer something and state why your offer is better. Right now it looks more like something you'd find on Visual.ly than a poster meant to increase sales.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very good. Everyone can clearly understand the service without the 3 step explanation. The cracked iPhone could look more like a shattered glass plate, rather than a textured surface. I don't like the copy (and the order of 3,1,2) because it is unnecessary. The logo on the fixed iPhone is gauche. That large logo on the iPhone makes me subconsciously think that TechBox owns the "shiny new" phone ... I would therefore want to take my broken iPhone to the Apple 'mother-ship' instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dean, I agree the logo is too "in your face" 

Do you think this approach solves that problem?


[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2FpeMF1mtttYUpYT1JrdHFvRWc/view?usp=sharing)  Putting the logo on more discretely the wrist band

Comment: The logo could be on the anti-static mat (bottom left) ... then it will be centric and more noticeable.

Comment: @IvanWitteborg I think the logo on the wrist band works well. You can also put the logo on the bottom left as Dean has mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, I've made a few changes to the poster and simplified it. I added the new poster to the original question. Let me know what you think.

Comment: It looks great. The message is clear and interesting to follow. The client will probably hate their logo so small but you have the business name and service in the center of the page, as large as can be. If I was TechBox I would go to print and take you out to lunch. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the logical, expected order of the three phones is not immediately apparent on first glance, and the explanatory text is necessary if you want to keep the current placement. Or you could move the shiny new phone down to the bottom to make for a more logical and easily recognized flow.